# MS Excel Power Query Data Connection using One Drive (multi person refresh issue)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery, datasource, onedrive

I am wanting to use Power Query to combine files in a specified folder. This issue is that currently I am the only one able to do the sync as the file path contains my personal path to one drive. I am unable to use a sharepoint link (or so I believe).

I have managed to amend the code in the Advanced Filter to look at a named range in the spreadsheet which contains the path name (so that anyone can amend that and then refresh the data - this was my theory)

However, in the data sources - the original path which I used to set up the connection still exists and if anyone tries to sync other than me - even though the path in the advanced filter is correct - it will still error stating it can't find my path! I am sooo close. I have tried to delete the original data source but it won't let me. I have tried clearing permissions, this doesn't work.

Can anyone help please?
Thanks
Angie.

I have tried connecting via web (I can't get authentication to work)
This issue is raised with Microsoft - they pointed me here.

I am on Business 365 so don't have the option of getting data from Sharepoint Folder

Comment: You have to post an example of what you are doing. Otherwise only religion can help.

Answer (score 0):

Please include sample data/sample code when asking a question here.

That said, your issue is a common one in Power Query, because Power Query hard-codes the file path into the M code. This is where you need a work-around.

Here's a scenario similar to yours, and maybe it will point you down the right path.

Assumptions:

1. Your data is located on OneDrive/SharePoint.
2. The query is located within the file in question.
3. Basically, you are trying to find the relative path of the file you're in at the moment, so you can manipulate it.

Steps:

1. Create a worksheet in your workbook that will contain this information. I call mine "Setup". In cell A1, enter the following formula and hit ENTER.

   =LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1),1)-1)
2. The expected output is the full path to the file on SharePoint, minus the file name itself.

   https://YOURCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/REST_OF_PATH
3. With the cell selected, to the left of the formula bar where you typically see the cell address ("A1" etc.), select the cell address and type in "FilePath". Once you got that, right-click on the worksheet tab and hide the sheet.

[image: Named Cell]

4. In Power Query, open the Advanced Editor for the query in question. Whatever your source is, replace it with the following:

   FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FilePath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],

   FullPathToFile1 = FilePath & "[YOUR_FILE_NAME].xlsx",

   Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(FullPathToFile1), null, true),

Basically, first you're defining what the relative file path is based on the formula you entered into the "Setup" worksheet, then you're pointing the source to that.

I have been using it like this for several projects, and it works great.